# How to intuitively understand larger than/less than operator in comparator of C++ priority queue container

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am always confused with defining the comparator for a priority queue container and don't know how to understand it. 
For example, I have a `vector` of `pair<int,int>`, where I want sort the pairs descendingly by its second field value.

So the codes looks like this:

```
 struct Compare
    {
        bool operator()(pair<int,int> const &p1, pair<int,int> const &p2) const
        {
            return p1.second < p2.second;
        }
    };



priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int> >, Compare> pqueue;
```

How to understand the operator `"<"` here because I thought it should be `">"` the first time and had to change it based on the result. Why is it `"<"` for descending order instead of `">"`? I just want to get it right at the first shot next time when I use `priority_queue`. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Priority queue returns the *top* element based on the comparison operator, meaning that when you retrieve items one by one, you get them in *descending* order.

The meaning of the comparison operator always stays *"less than"*, meaning that when `compare(A, B)` is true, `B` has higher priority than `A`, and would be returned earlier from the priority queue.

Inverting the comparison function inverts the order in which you get the items from your priority queue. Specifically, using `>` in place of `<` reverses the order to *ascending*.

Answer (score 0):

In a way you are right to feel a little disconcerted because we could associate most priority to higher values and that could be counter-intuitive.

But in a priority queue it is usually assumed that the priority order is from the lowest value to the highest. That is, the minimum element of the set has the highest priority and so on.

I think the intuitive reason for this "inversion" is related to the fact that many greedy algorithms prioritize lower costs on higher ones and in order to manage that, these algorithms can use a priority queue of costs.